# the pairs which are conjugate to each other in the respective groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Pick out the pairs which are conjugate to each other in the respective groups:-

(a)$\begin {bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\0&1 \end {bmatrix} $ and  $\begin {bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\1&1 \end {bmatrix} $ in $GL_n \mathbb({R})$

(b)$\begin {bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\0&1 \end {bmatrix} $ and  $\begin {bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\1&1 \end {bmatrix} $ in $SL_n \mathbb({R})$

(c)$\begin {bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\0&2 \end {bmatrix} $ and  $\begin {bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\0&2 \end {bmatrix} $ in $GL_n \mathbb({R})$

---

$A$ and $B$ will be conjugate if there exist a invertible matrix $P$  such that $PA=BP$.
Now solving the matrices given in (a) and (b) I get $P$ must be $0$.
But (a) and (c) are correct.
So I am confused .Is my process correct?

Comment: do you mind to write down how did you get zero for $P$?

Comment: taking $A=[1,1;0,1]$ and B=[1,0;1,1]$ I get $P=0$

Comment: I would take it as kidding... I know you are taking $A,B$ as you have stated but i am not getting $P=0$ so there could be some mistake in my evaluation or yours so please write down each step and we will see if there is any error.

Comment: My latex is not so strong so wright so many lines is very tough for me.

Comment: Can me tell me please that my process is right or wrong? and what is the actual process?

Answer (score 1):

Considering $A=\begin {bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\0&1 \end {bmatrix}; B=\begin {bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\1&1 \end {bmatrix}$ we would work out for $P=\begin {bmatrix} a & b \\c&d \end {bmatrix}$ such that $PA=BP$

$PA=\begin {bmatrix} a & b \\c&d \end {bmatrix}\begin {bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\0&1 \end {bmatrix}=\begin {bmatrix} a & a+b \\c&c+d \end {bmatrix}$

$BP=\begin {bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\1&1 \end {bmatrix}\begin {bmatrix} a & b \\c&d \end {bmatrix}=\begin {bmatrix} a & b \\a+c&b+d \end {bmatrix}$

$AP=BP$ would say that $a=0$ and $b=c$ ; It would not say anything about $d$.

Infact there are infinitely many matrices $P$ such that $PA=BP$ and only one matrix is not in $Gl_n(\mathbb{R})$

So, $A$ and $B$ are conjugate...

Coming to second part we need to see if $P$ is in special linear group that is with determinant $1$.

I guess you can see that no $P$ defined as above is in $Sl_n(\mathbb{R})$.

I would leave third question to you.

Good luck!